# Getting error when calculating sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, reshape

I am trying to calculate the ndcg score of a classifier but I am getting this error:

> ValueError: Only ('multilabel-indicator', 'continuous-multioutput', 'multiclass-multioutput') formats are supported. Got multiclass instead

Here's my code:

```py
# Declare classifier, fit on data and make predictions
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rnd_forest = RandomForestClassifier()
rnd_forest.fit(X_train_tr, y_train)
y_pred_prob = rnd_forest.predict_proba(X_train_tr)

# Calculate ndcg score
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score
# This is where I get an error
ndcg_score(y_train, y_pred_prob, k=5)
```

This is what my target and predicted probabilities look like:

```py
# True labels of the first two samples
y_train[:2]
> array([7, 7])
    
# Predicted probabilities for first two observation
y_pred_prob[:2]
> array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I tried to reshape `y_train` into a 2-D array but it's not working. Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `N` observations in `y_train`. You have to transform `y_train` to a matrix of `N` rows and `12` columns.

```py
# Create an ndarray of size (N, 12) filled with zeros
y_train_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(y_pred_prob.shape[0], y_pred_prob.shape[1]))
# Write a 1 on each row's corresponding category
y_train_matrix[np.arange(y_pred_prob.shape[0]), y_train] = 1
# You now have this ndarray
y_train_matrix

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Now you can calculate the score:

```py
ndcg_score(y_train_matrix, y_pred_prob)

1.0
```